# How to install phpunit in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit

I have `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and I want to install `phpunit` for `PHP 7.1` through terminal. I do the same steps as in `https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html` but I always have `PHPUnit 5.1.3` instead of `PHPUnit 7.0.0` by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system does not (really) matter. The installation for PHPUnit is explained [here](https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html).

Comment: I know that link, but when I do the same steps for php 7 which I have I got the following when I check phpunit version:
 PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. Instead of PHPUnit 7.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors as in the link.

Comment: You probably have an old `phpunit` on your `$PATH`. Simply invoking `phpunit` will execute that. You need to explicitly invoke the one you installed, for instance with `./vendor/bin/phpunit` (Composer install) or `./phpunit.phar` (PHAR download).